# Having trouble with constructors which accepts different parameters

Tags: c++, class, oop, object, constructor

I am new to C++ and I am having trouble with class and header files. I am trying to create a constructor to accept various pokemon stats such as strings and integers. I used to code in java and constructors were fairly simple to assign.

Pokemons.h

```
    #ifndef POKEMONS_H
    #define POKEMONS_H
    #include <string>
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    class Pokemons {
    public:
    Pokemons();

    };
    #endif /* POKEMONS_H */
```

Pokemons.cpp

```
    #include "Pokemons.h"
    #include <string>

    using namespace std;


        string pokemonName;
        string pokemonType1;
        string pokemonType2;
        int pokemonHP;
        int pokemonAttack;
        int pokemonDefence;
        int pokemonSPAttack;
        int pokemonSPDefence;
        int pokemonSpeed;

        Pokemons::Pokemons(string nm, string tp1, string tp2, int hp, int atk, 
        int def, int satk, int sdef, int spd) {

            pokemonName      = nm;
            pokemonType1     = tp1;
            pokemonType2     = tp2;
            pokemonHP        = hp;
            pokemonAttack    = atk;
            pokemonDefence   = def;
            pokemonSPAttack  = satk;
            pokemonSPDefence = sdef;
            pokemonSpeed     = spd;
        }
```

main.cpp

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include "Pokemons.h"

    int main(){

        Pokemons p001;
        p001.Pokemons("Bulbasaur", "Grass", "None", 31,23,45,43,45,12);
        return 0;

    }
```

I am getting the following errors :

```
Pokemons.cpp:32:9: error: prototype for 'Pokemons::Pokemons(std::string, std::string, std::string, int, int, int, int, int, int)' does not match any in class 'Pokemons'
         Pokemons::Pokemons(string nm, string tp1, string tp2, int hp, int atk, int def, int satk, int sdef, int spd) {


In file included from Pokemons.cpp:14:0:
Pokemons.h:21:7: error: candidates are: constexpr Pokemons::Pokemons(Pokemons&&)
 class Pokemons {


Pokemons.h:21:7: error:                 constexpr Pokemons::Pokemons(const Pokemons&)
Pokemons.cpp:30:9: error:                 Pokemons::Pokemons()
         Pokemons::Pokemons(){}
```

Comment: A few things for you to google: "in class initialization", "initialization list". Don't use the constructor body unless you *have to*.

Comment: `pokemonName` ... `pokemonSpeed` should be in your class definition instead of global variables in your source file.

Comment: All member declarations should be inside the class definition, not outside of it. (It will look a lot like the corresponding Java.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three problems here. First, your constructor is *declared* as `Pokemons();`, taking zero arguments, but you have a constructor *defined* as taking many arguments, and so their signatures don't match, and ultimately, because of function overloading in C++, they refer to different functions. Try declaring the constructor as follows in your header file:

```
class Pokemons {
    public:
    Pokemons(string nm, string tp1, string tp2, int hp, int atk, 
        int def, int satk, int sdef, int spd);
};
```

Now both the definition and declaration should refer to the same function.

The second problem is here:

```
Pokemons p001;
```

This *implicitly calls* the constructor with no arguments. It's important to understand that many functions get called in C++ even though they haven't been explicitly named. To fix this, you should initialize `p001` as follows:

```
Pokemons p001("Bulbasaur", "Grass", "None", 31,23,45,43,45,12);
```

You should also remove `p001.Pokemons("Bulbasaur", "Grass", "None", 31,23,45,43,45,12);` on the following line. Now, the compiler can match this call to your constructor taking many arguments.

The third problem for now is that `pokemonName` all the way through `pokemonSpeed` are defined *outside* the `Pokemons` class, in global scope. This has a similar effect to making a member `static` in Java. These should be placed inside your class definition, to make them instance members:

```
class Pokemons {
    public:
    Pokemons(string nm, string tp1, string tp2, int hp, int atk, 
        int def, int satk, int sdef, int spd);

    private:

    string pokemonName;
    string pokemonType1;
    string pokemonType2;
    int pokemonHP;
    int pokemonAttack;
    int pokemonDefence;
    int pokemonSPAttack;
    int pokemonSPDefence;
    int pokemonSpeed;
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but now I am getting the following errors:  main.cpp:20:18: error: no matching function for call to 'Pokemons::Pokemons()'
         Pokemons p001;
                  ^~~~
I
Pokemons.h:21:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
Pokemons.h:21:7: note: candidate: constexpr Pokemons::Pokemons(Pokemons&&)
Pokemons.h:21:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
main.cpp:21:14: error: invalid use of 'Pokemons::Pokemons'
         p001.Pokemons("Bulbasaur", "Grass", "None", 31,23,45,43,45,12);

Comment: I feel kinda dumb right now. Thank you, kind sir for helping me out!.

Comment: No problem. C++ has a rather steep learning curve and a messy history compared to Java.